# Selenium cannot find discord (in browser) element

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, automation

I'm trying to join a discord server via Selenium. Unfortunately it seems like Selenium is not able to locate the 'join server' element and hence I'm not able to click on it. I've tried finding it by XPATH, CSS-Selector, ID, Name and so on, none seems to be working.
It's weird, because there are elements on the frontpage which do work fine and I am able to locate them by `driver.find_element_by_...`.
Appreciate any help guys! :^)

`folder_path = r"C:\Users\..."`

````
fp.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
fp.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
fp.set_preference("marionette.enabled", False)
fp.update_preferences()
desired = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, desired_capabilities=desired)

driver.get("https://discord.com/channels/@me")
join_server = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
joined_server_xpath)))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,joined_server_xpath).click() ```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edited the previous question. Somehow I dont see the xpath. ```joined_server_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/div[24]/div[1]/div/div/svg/foreignObject/div/svg/path' ```

Comment: Please add the `HTML` source for the element, this web require login to access that element

Comment: sorry I'm relatively new to operating with html, but do you need the whole source code, the body html, or just the html from the 'join sever' element?